# find a plane equation

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

I'm having some trouble in finding the plane which the distance between it and the point $(-1,0,1)$ is: $2$ and also it passes through the points $(0,0,6)$ and $(2,0,3)$.

I tried to start by finding the line that passes through those points $(0,0,6)$ and $(2,0,3)$ so I find this line which the plain consists and I got stuck finding the  normal of the plane by the dot product with the direction vector of the line because I don't find a connection to $B$  $(Ax+By+Cz+D=0)$, so therefore $B$ can be anything which because of that I can't find a specific equation for the needed plane or planes for that matter (if because of the distance we will get two options) . Would love some help figuring this one out. thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site.  To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs.  For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$.  You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: Now is it better?

Comment: Yes, it's much easier to read, and looks nicer, too.

Comment: Thank you :) will try also for next time.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing it correctly.  I can't tell where you are bogged down.  I got that the equation of the plane is $By+3z=9$, and you say, we don't know $B$ yet.  But we can project $(1,0-1)$ onto the plane, and then calculate the distance.  This will depend on $B$, of course, so we set it equal to $2$ and solve for $B$.  What goes wrong?  Please add some more details of your calculations.

Comment: thank you so much first. My bad, I wrote the wrong dot. it is $(0,0,6)$ not $(0,0,3)$ and therefore my problem. I will change it now.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ax+by+cz=d$ be the plane in question. It goes thru $(0,0.3)$ and $(2,0,3)\implies a\cdot 0+b\cdot 0+c\cdot 3 = d\implies d = 3c$. Also, $a\cdot 2+ b\cdot 0+ c\cdot 3=d=3c\implies a=0\implies by+cz=3c$ is the equation of the plane. We still need to find $b,c$. The distance is now used: $\dfrac{|b\cdot 0+ c\cdot 1-3c|}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}=2\implies 4c^2=4(b^2+c^2)\implies b = 0\implies cz=3c\implies z =3$ is the equation of the plane.

**Note:** This answer is based on the unedited post. With the edited post, the $(0,0,3)$ is changed to $(0,0,6)$, and the analysis is the same but with a different equation for the plane.

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry again for the mistake with the dot. One more thing if I get finally an equation which is all with $C$ in which $B$≠$0$ and $A$≠$0$ then in order to find the plane equation can I divide it by $C$ in order to get it?

Comment: @mathmagic: Yes,  you can divide by $c$ to get the equation.

Comment: Great, thank you :)

Comment: @mathmagic: Sure, any time. My plez.